Deciding polynomial ambiguity (in input size or height) of a tree automaton — already known or not?
Let A be a tree automaton over a ranked alphabet Σ, and f : Tree(Σ) → ℕ be its ambiguity, i.e. f(t) counts the number of accepting runs of A over t.

Is there a proof in the literature of the following result: it is decidable whether f is bounded by a polynomial in the input size, and the optimum polynomial degree is computable? I have my own proof inspired by this master's thesis https://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~epaul/Diplom_Thesis.pdf which looks at the structure of polynomially ambiguous tree automata but without considering computability questions. For strings this is explicitly shown in https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-16078-7_74 and https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(91)90381-B (but probably implicit in older work on ℕ-rational series?).
What about "bounded by a polynomial in the input height"? The notion comes up at least in this paper https://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~maletti/pub/malnasstiulb21.pdf but again, without any decidability result.

(For some context, this came up in ongoing work on tree transducers, cf. slide 9 of https://nguyentito.eu/2024-06-irif.pdf — it mentions the functions computed by ℕ-weighted tree automata, but that's essentially the same as the ambiguity of tree NFA.)
